# Is there a way to use findstr to search for a value and return the line that value is on within a text file?

Tags: batch-file

I want to find a value within a text file that has 120+ lines of values, then set the line that the value was found on as a variable so i can go back and replace the value in the text file with another value.

Using this line

```
   for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /c:/-59/12/ ScreenData.txt') do set 
   var=%%a
```

i can find the value (coordinate) /-59/12/ within the text (ScreenData.txt) and then assign it to the variable (var).
I can then echo %var% and get the output /-59/12/, but there is no way to then replace /-59/12/ with (the letter H for example).

I have tried...

```
   for %%g in (findstr /n "/-58/12/" ScreenData.txt) do set var=%%g
```

the text doc has /-58/12/  as the 2nd line, however the output was ScreenData.txt not 2.

This is the code leading up to the replacement...

```
   REM --- ROW a ---

   SET /A rowa1x=%xaxis%-59
   SET /A rowa1y=%yaxis%+12
   SET rowa1=/%rowa1x%/%rowa1y%/

   SET /A rowa2x=%xaxis%-58
   SET /A rowa2y=%yaxis%+12
   SET rowa2=/%rowa2x%/%rowa2y%/

   SET /A rowa60x=%xaxis%
   SET /A rowa60y=%yaxis%+12
   SET rowa60=/%rowa60x%/%rowa60y%/

   REM --- Export Values ---

   (
   echo %rowa1% 
   echo %rowa2% 
   echo %rowa60%
   ) >ScreenData.txt ---

   pause

   REM --- View Generator

   for %%g in (findstr /n "/-58/12/" ScreenData.txt) do set var=%%g

   echo %var%

   pause
```

I'm sure i'm just going about this in the wrong way.

so the logic is...

find a value equal to /-58/12/ in the text file.
what line is it on?
it is on the 3rd line.
replace the 3rd line with "H".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q55875551.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('type "%filename1%"') DO (
 IF "%%a"=="/-59/12/" (
  ECHO H
 ) ELSE (
  ECHO %%a
 )
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q55875551.txt` containing some dummy data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

Empty data lines will be removed.

This simply changes any line which is exactly "/-59/12/" to "H". You would need to provide examples of other transformations you might want.

The layout I have used is deliberately verbose for versatility.

Comment: I cannot seem to get it to work. When i run the batch it immediately closes. Does the batch file itself need a specific name?  Not sure if there's an extra step.

Comment: It would seem you are executing this batch by way of a "Short Cut." If you add a line `pause` just before the `goto :eof` then the window will remain open. If you change `@echo off` to `@echo on` then you should get a run report which should reveal any problems. I'd suggest you start with a very short test file - just a few lines - as this would likely make the report easier to read. Also be aware that batch has some sensitivity to layout, so if you are using a word-processor to cut-and paste, you're much better off using a text editor like `editplus` filename is not relevant - fred.bat is OK

Comment: So when i did that it is saying the system cannot find path specified. I have a txt file named q55875551.txt that has the following values in it: /-59/12/
/-53/13/
/-57/17/
/-51/16/
/-59/14/ The first line has the value it should be looking for, but i'm not sure i have it set up right if it can't find it.

Comment: After the `setlocal` line, add a line `echo %cd%` which will show you the current directory in which the batch is running (this is just for information). You need to `set` the value of `sourcedir` to the directory in which your text file resides, not `U:\sourcedir`. Similarly, set `destdir` to your desired destination directory, and change the filenames `outfile.txt` and `q55875551.txt` to suit your system. I use `u:\sourcedir` on my system as it's on a ramdrive and disappears when I reboot. I use `q55875551.txt` as a filename because this is SO question number 55875551. There's no magic here.